# Angular 4 - AnimationPlayer deprecated, how do I target the current animation

Tags: angular, animation

I successfully created an new Angular 4 project. I added the BrowserAnimationModule to my app.module.ts, and my basic animations work. However, in an earlier version of angular 2, I was able to target the current AnimationPlayer from @angular/core using ViewContainerRef like this:

```
this._ref['_element'].parentView.viewChildren[0].animationPlayers._allPlayers[0]._activePlayer._player;
```

It worked very well, and I was able to get the current time, play state, playback rate, etc.

Does anyone know how target the _activePlayer._player equivalent in Angular 4?

Thanks.